# same Path with REST for 2 Different Modules in Wildfly

Tags: java, rest, jboss, wildfly

I am using Wildfly 9 and have 2 different Modules (Wars) I deploy and declare as an Application (Servlet).

I use Dynamic Web Modules v 3.1 and Application Subclasses with an PathAnnotation without an web.xml file.

Now every Module-Path has his own Package-Name in it.
For Example Test-Modul `localhost:8080/testmodul/` and so one.
But i need 2 different War files to listen on the same path, like `localhost:8080/api`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found a way because it is possible:

In Wildfly you can create an file named "jboss-web.xml" and put it in the WEB-INF folder of the module.

In this xml you now can define different things that are not possible in web.xml or on other way.
For Example you can use the option < context-root > to define the path of a module. In my Example the jboss-web.xml would look like this:

```
<jboss-web>
<context-root>/api/modules</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Now you can reach both deployed modules under:
www.localhost:8080/api/modules

There are also a lot other possible commands, which you can read about here:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/appdev/jbossweb.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have to different deployments that share the same context. But the desired result could be achieved by using a reverse proxy in front of the application server.